Event study - Fama French 3 factor model - T-value too high?
I have to do an event study with the Fama French 3 factor model for a portfolio consisting of the 10 largest US tech companies for the last 24 years for my master thesis, which I unfortunately have to hand in on Monday :(.
The event is the President's annual State of the Union address.
Event window is t-1 to t+5
Estimation window is t-11 to t-211
I calculated the alpha and the betas with a regression also with t-11 to t-211.
I have actually calculated everything as shown in Youtube videos and as given by the formula.
However, when I want to test my abnormal returns from significance, I sometimes get a very high t-value, sometimes -10 or even -22, which somehow can't be right. I wonder where my error lies.
Enclosed is my Excel. Please help, I'm a bit desperate haha
https://onedrive.live.com/?id=245DBD4054154469%21s677dbedda90b482d8bd55bbd3a4f449f&cid=245DBD4054154469
https://1drv.ms/f/c/245dbd4054154469/Et2-fWcLqS1Ii9VbvTpPRJ8B-WtlPZsxspApP9ONhtsTcQ?e=eY7dq4
If the link does not work, please write
